# I can't write logs to a file using a specific channel with Monolog in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, monolog

I try to write logs to a specific file using a specific channel in Monolog (called encuestas_cloud) inside a Command in Symfony 3.4 but I'm not able to do it.

I've read Symfony docs and searched in the web and I think it's well configured but i get an error.

The code is:

In config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        channels: ['!event']

  ...
    encuestas_cloud_logger:
        #type: rotating_file
        type: stream
        path: 'D:/web/xampp/htdocs/temp/logs/encuestas_cloud.log'
        level: info
        channels: ['encuestas_cloud']   
        max_files: 10
```

In services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: true
     public: false

  AppBundle\Command\EncuestasCloudCommand\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php'
    arguments: ['@logger']
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: encuestas_cloud }
```

The command:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php
namespace AppBundle\Command;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
...

class EncuestasCloudCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct();
  }

 ...
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {

    $logger = $this->logger;
    $logger->addInfo('My logger is now ready');
```

When I execute it I get:

> In LoggerChannelPass.php line 98:
>
> Monolog configuration error: The logging channel "encuestas_cloud" assigned to the
>     "encuestas_cloud_logger" handler does not exist.
>
> In ContainerBuilder.php line 1063:
>
> You have requested a non-existent service "monolog.logger.encuestas_cloud".

If I add `channels: ['encuestas_cloud']`  in config_dev.yml

```
monolog:
  channels: ['encuestas_cloud'] 

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
...
```

The error dissappear but the log still goes to the general log file: dev.log

Please, could somebody help me to find out what is wrong with the configuration?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: did you check [https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_console.html]? obviously basic logging is configured for commands to output to console.

Comment: I want a command to be executed automatically every day and I wanted to put some info in a log file to check and to send an email in case of error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot [evertjes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087536/evertjes) for your answer, it didn't solve the problem but helped me to investigate other paths...

The problem was that the command wasn't defined as a service in the right way, so Symfony was unable to match the channel to the service (and to the command).

I executed :

```
php bin/console debug:container
```

and the service of the command didn't appear.

So after investigating how to define a command as a service the configuration worked fine... uffff.

Here I post the final code that works.

In config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:
  channels: ['encuestas_cloud']

  handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        channels: ['!event','!encuestas_cloud']

  ...
    encuestas_cloud_logger:
        type: rotating_file
        path: 'D:/web/xampp/htdocs/temp/logs/encuestas_cloud.log'
        level: info
        channels: ['encuestas_cloud']   
        max_files: 10
```

In services.yml

```
services:
  _defaults:
     autowire: true
     autoconfigure: true
     public: false

  console.command.encuestas_cloud_command:
    class: 'AppBundle\Command\EncuestasCloudCommand'
    arguments: ['@logger']
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: encuestas_cloud }
```

The command:

```
// src/AppBundle/Command/EncuestasCloudCommand.php
namespace AppBundle\Command;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
...

class EncuestasCloudCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand

{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct();
  }

 ...
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {

    $logger = $this->logger;
    $logger->addInfo('My logger is now ready');
```

Now the file is created and the log appears with the configured channel.

Thanks a lot to everybody!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does changing the argument for your Command from `@logger` to `@monolog.logger.encuestas_cloud` work? That should inject the specific configured logger and therefor your logging would appear in the correct logger.

```
monolog:
  channels: ['encuestas_cloud']
```

Should be defined AFAIK, and explicitly excluding the channel for your `main` logger, to not appear there:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            ...
            channels: [ '!encuestas_cloud' ]
```